# How to count the number of times value exists in line?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

My Data like this..,

```
[123:1000,156,132,123,156,123]
[123:1009,392,132,123,156,123]
[234:987,789,132,123,156,123]
[234:8765,789,132,123,156,123]
```

I need to count number of times "123" exists in each line using expression language in nifi.

I need to do it in expression language only.How can i count it?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`SplitContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitText/index.html) processor to split the flowfile content into individual flowfiles per line, then use [`ExtractText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html) with a regex like `pattern`=`(123)?` which will result in an attribute being added to the flowfile for each matching group:

`[123:1009,392,132,123,156,123] -> pattern.1, pattern.2, pattern.3
[234:987,789,132,123,156,123] -> pattern.1, pattern.2`

Finally, you can use a [`ScanAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ScanAttribute/index.html) processor to detect the attribute with the highest group count in each of the flowfiles and route it to an [`UpdateAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateAttribute/index.html) to put that value into a common flowfile attribute (i.e. `count`). You could also replace some steps with an [`ExecuteStreamCommand`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) and use a variety of OS-level tools (`grep`/`awk`/`sed`/`cut`/etc.) to perform the count, return that value, and update the content of the flowfile.

It would probably be simpler for you to perform this count action within an [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor, as it could be done in 1-2 lines of Groovy, Ruby, Python, or Javascript, and would not require multiple processors. Apache NiFi is designed for data routing and simple transformation, not complex event processing, so there are not standard processors developed for these tasks. There is an open Jira for ["Add processor to perform simple aggregations"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2735) which has a [patch available here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/988), which may be useful for you.

Comment: ,i have using this ${allMatchingAttributes("pattern.*"):contains("123"):count()} it will return wrongly if patttern,pattern.0,pattern.1 contains 123 so it will return 3 but it it could be return 2 only not to add pattern attribute with pattern.1,pattern.2

Comment: There is a boolean configuration value to capture group 0 in the `ExtractText` processor. Set this to `false`, and it will not add an attribute for the entire regex match.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#count) a count is done like this:

```
${allMatchingAttributes(".*"):contains("123"):count()}
```

Comment: ,Which Processor workflows i have to create to run your query?

Comment: What about `1234`? Will it match it?

Comment: @Mahendran I am not familiar with NiFi, I just pointed out, that the linked documentation answers the question on how to count. It looks like your initial problem is not "count occurences" but "how to query at all". I suggest you get familiar with the fundamentals of Apache NiFi.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais I honestly don't know, but from the documentation I'd guess, that a list item "123" is not the same as "1234". Using `matches("123+")` or `startsWith("123")` should match everything beginning with "123"

Comment: @Oli, your answer is close. `allMatchingAttributes(".*")` will iterate over all available *attributes*, and count how many of those attributes contain the string `123`. In this case, I do not believe the data is in an attribute, so it would not quite be correct. In addition, it would not count the number of times `123` was contained within *each* attribute.